# EiffelStudio, project read-only: cannot compile

Tags: compilation, eiffel

I'm making a shared project with my university in Eiffel. I've just downloaded the project and I've got this problem:

We have to work on a `NameProject_as_library.ecf`, so we have to work on an as_library type. The problem is here, that's doesn't compile because gets out a pop-up message with written `Read-only project: cannot compile`.

I've tried to search in EiffelStudio any option for this problem and I found the option `Library readonly = true/false` in project -> project settings. It was set on true, so I turned on false and nothing is changed.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: This might sound silly, but... are there are *files* (or directories, such as an output directory) marked by your operating system as RO? Have you tried making the project directory (and all children) Read-Write?

Comment: I've redownladed the project and now it seems to work. I think that is a problem with the virtualization of eiffelstudio on Mac. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this simply a unix permission issue? Have you write rights to your directory and to NameProject_as_library.ecf?

Comment: I've redownladed the project and now it seems to work. I think that is a problem with the virtualization of eiffelstudio on Mac. Thanks for the answer